# What preprocessing technique can help me to filter the background text noises using matlab...the image is shown below?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, ocr

[image: A]

Can anyone help me to improve the degradation of the following image....i am working on OCR system in Amharic language and what is the best image filtering technique that can help me to separate text data from background noise?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called *(ink) bleeding*. A popular approach is to separate or segment the document image using [graphical models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model). Relevant papers include:

- Document Ink Bleed-Through Removal with Two Hidden Markov Random Fields and a Single Observation Field
- User-Assisted Ink-Bleed Reduction
- Bleed-through removal in degraded documents
- Directed Assistance for Ink-Bleed Reduction in Old Documents
- Ink-Bleed Reduction Using Functional Minimization

Comment: can you lead me to some matlab source codes that can make me to do it?

Comment: I'd recommend looking for the home pages of the authors. They frequently post their code. More recently you also find academic repositories on github. Your problem is tractable if technically challenging!